Can time slicing and context switches cause high CPU utilization in a Java based application?
I have a Play framework application with about 400 threads. 200 are part of the default dispatcher.
Now I have 2 db sources with 9 connections each and thread pool with a min size of 20 and max of 200. All db operations are performed inside a db execution context.
Under normal load( <50 req/sec), the CPU usage is just fine. However, if we go up to 70 or 80 requests per second then utilization spikes and some APIS start becoming unresponsive.
My reasoning was that once the connections were all occupied, the dispatcher created a task queue for all new incoming requests. I assumed that since dispatcher has no idea that the underlying operation is blocking, it spawned as many threads as the tasks and all of these threads tried to invoke getConnection on ebean which is a synchronized block. At that point I would expect significant resources to go into managing the locks, allocating time for all of these threads to check if any of the connections became available(time slicing) and context switching.
Am I on the right track? Is there a way confirm this theory and measure the cpu utilization caused by this? I have read about JMX for viewing thread level CPU utilization but I wasn't sure how it would work. Lastly, the only improvement to this design that I can see is to have a separate thread pool for both db sources and to match the number of threads to the number of connections.
I do have some thread dump snapshots where I can see some threads are blocked and most are in waiting. However, it is not clear whether waiting implies .get() or .join() blocking operation or if thread is just idle(thread.sleep())
Edit -
I looked at newrelic and a thread dump snapshot and both of them showed only 20 threads. I am feeling skeptical about this now. Is there another front I should also be checking out like GC?

Yes. Context switching can kill your performance. You could try visualvm. Also, can you use fibers instead of threads?

maybe another use case for Virtual Threads (Java 21)

@user85421 I agree but for that I will have to migrate to Play 3.0 and that is not feasible at the moment.

What do you mean by this: “All db operations are performed inside a db execution context.”?

What version of Play? Of Java?

You don’t need Play 3 for virtual threads. Play 2.9 supports Java 21 according to Wikipedia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Flight_Recorder and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDK_Mission_Control

What database engine? What JDBC driver?

@BasilBourque I mean we use supplyAsync with an execution context specifically made for db operations. It is supposed to have a min of 20 threads and max of 200
We are using mysql with ebean(I think that also uses jdbc internally)
